# Show Prestashop Layered Navigation Block and All Products on Home Page

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I am creating an e-commerce website on the platform of prestashop. I tried various ways to to show the product filters i.e. ***Layered Navigation Block*** to appear on the home page. How can I do this ? I'm using the default theme of Prestashop.

Also, on the home page, only a few products are being displayed. For Example, only the popular and the best seller products are being displayed. Instead, I wish to display all the products on the home page. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "Home featured products" and set a necessary number of products to display in it in order to show more products on your homepage. It is the simplest way to solve your requirements with products, in another case you need to use some third-party modules to do it. What about the second point, you can't use default Layered Navigation Module outside the Category pages so you also need a third-party module to do this or need to make some development to the module.